# How to debug my decimal to binary conversion program?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code

I have created a code to for decimal to binary conversion, but I'm having issues in the output.

Have a look at the output then the code.

**Output:**

```
Decimal to Binary Conversion
Enter Number
58
rem = 0
rem = 1
rem = 0
rem = 1
rem = 1
rem = 1
Binary = 1111 // here it should print 111010 (the obtained remainders in reverse order)
```

Code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    void decimalToBinary(){

int n,i,rem;

    cout<<"Decimal to Binary Conversion"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter Number"<<endl;
    cin>>n; 

    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    rem=n%2; 
    n=n/2; 

     
     cout<<"rem = "<<rem<<endl;

     if (n == 1){ 
         break;
     } 
     else if (n == 0){ 
         break; 
     }
    
}
    cout <<"rem = " << n << endl;
    cout << "Binary = " << n << rem << rem << rem << endl;

    


    }
    int main()

{

    decimalToBinary();

    return 0;
}
```

How can I attain the required output? I should be able to achieve the output in reverse order.

Comment: Focus on `cout << rem << rem << rem` and understand that it is a directive to print the same value several times.  Or focus on `rem=n%2;` and understand that you are _replacing_ an old value with a new value.  At no point has your function stored "all the bits" - only the most recent bit.

Comment: yes i already know this but is there any way to do it without using array and string ?

Comment: Consider making an [edit] to your question to clarify what your question actually is.  You did not mention any requirements regarding the avoidance of arrays and strings.  Only that you needed _help attaining the required output_.  People may avoid answering you if they think you are going to change the question after they answer.

Comment: You can loop over the bits from top to bottom using `(n >> i) & 1` to access bit `i` of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the below line properly:

```
cout << "Binary = " << n << rem << rem << rem << endl;
```

See? You are basically printing out `n` 1 time and `rem` 3 times, which will definitely not give you the desired output.

The following works:

```
// ...
#include <algorithm>

void decimalToBinary() {

    int n, rem;
    std::string binary; // This will store our binary number

    cout << "Decimal to Binary Conversion" << endl;
    cout << "Enter Number" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        rem = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;

        cout << "rem = " << rem << endl;
        binary.push_back(std::to_string(rem)[0]);

        if (n == 1) {
            break;
        }
        else if (n == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "rem = " << n << endl;

    reverse(binary.begin(), binary.end()); // Reverse the string `binary`
    cout << "Binary = " << n << binary << endl;
}

// ...
```

Comment: I'm already familiar with this method is there any possible way to get the desired output without using strings/arrays.

Comment: binary.push_back(std::to_string(rem)[0]);   // what does this mean?

Comment: `std::to_string(rem)` converts `rem` (which is an `int`) to a `std::string`. binary.push_back(char) inserts a character into binary. For ex: if binary == "ab", then binary.push_back('c'); will insert 'c' into binary, which means now `binary == "abc"`. Note that we cannot push in entire `strings` into a `string`, we can only `push_back()` characters, so that's why I used `[0]` to access the first character of the `std::string` returned by `std::to_string()`, which is then pushed back into `binary`.